# Trying to write a bare-metal SD card interface in C - no external libraries

Tags: c, interface, sd-card, bare-metal

I am trying to write a simple bare-metal interface to talk to an SD card via SPI, and I'm struggling to get the responses I thought.

I have a simple initialisation and then I try to read the sector size.

I have tried with two different manufacturers (Kingston and SanDisk). The Kingston responds to CMD55 and then CMD1, but the SanDisk does not respond at all. I would appreciate if someone could point out what I am missing.

Response from Kingston

```
 CMD8 voltage 55
 Send CMD55
 05 ff ff ff ff ff ff
 Size 3fffff
 SectorCount = 0
 0 sector count
 Initialization complete!
```

Response from SanDisk

```
 Send CMD55
 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
 Size 3fffff
 SectorCount = 0
 0 sector count
 Initialization complete!
```

Here is the code:

```c
// Define the base physical address for the SD card
#define SD_CARD_BASE_ADDRESS (*(volatile uint32_t *)(0xC00000D0))
#define SD_CARD_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL (*(volatile uint32_t *)(0xC00000D4))
#define SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL (*(volatile uint32_t *)(0xC00000D8))

// Chip select state macros
#define SD_SELECT() (SD_CARD_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x00)        // Set chip select low (active)
#define SD_DESELECT() (SD_CARD_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x01)      // Set chip select high (inactive)

const uint8_t CMD0[]  =  {0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x95, 0xFF};    // GO_IDLE_STATE
const uint8_t CMD1[]  =  {0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF9, 0xFF};    // use for old card instead of CMD55
const uint8_t CMD8[]  =  {0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xAA, 0x87, 0xFF};    // SEND_IF_COND
const uint8_t CMD16[] =  {0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x81, 0xFF};    // SET_BLOCKLEN, block size = 512 bytes
const uint8_t CMD9[]  =  {0x49, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF};    //(READ_CSD)   AF
const uint8_t CMD55[] =  {0x77, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF};    // APP_CMD
const uint8_t CMD58[] =  {0x7A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF};    // READ_OCR
const uint8_t ACMD41[] = {0x69, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF};    // SD_SEND_OP_COND

void spi_transmit(uint8_t data) {
    for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
        SD_CARD_BASE_ADDRESS = ((data >> j) & 0x01);            //write value
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x00;               //clock low
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x01;               //clock high
    }
}

uint8_t spi_receive() {
    uint8_t data = 0;
    bool startBitReceived = false;
    int watchdogTimeout = 80;           // Set the desired watchdog timeout
    int miso = 0;
   
    for (int c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL &= 0xFE;  // Clock low
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL |= 0x01;  // Clock high
        miso = (SD_CARD_BASE_ADDRESS & 0x01);       //read the bit

        if (startBitReceived == false) {
            if (miso == 0) {
                // Start bit received, mark it as received
                startBitReceived = true;
                data = 0;
            } else {
                // Start bit not received, continue waiting
                c++;
                watchdogTimeout--;
                if (watchdogTimeout == 0) {
                    return 0xFF;
                }
            }
        }
        if (miso !=0) data |= 1 << c;
    }
    return data;
}

//Sends command and if length > 0 then waits for a response 
void SendCMD(const uint8_t *cmd, uint8_t res[], uint32_t length) {
    
    for (int c = 0;c<7; c++){
        spi_transmit(cmd[c]);
    }
        
    if (length > 0){
        //gets a response
        res[0] = spi_receive();

        if (res[0] == 0xFF){
            printf("Timeout - spi_receive \n\r");
            return;
        }

        for (int c = 1; c < length; c++){
            res[c] =  spi_receive();
        }
    
    }
}

//attempt to get sector count 
uint32_t get_sector_count() {
    uint8_t res[10];

    //dummy writes - note sure this is required
    spi_transmit(0xFF);
    spi_transmit(0xFF);

    // Send CMD9 command - do not wait here for response 
    SendCMD(CMD9, res, 0);

    // Ideally, wait for the data token (0xFE) but never happens
    //  while (spi_receive() != 0xFE);

    // Skip to byte 7 to get C_SIZE field (bits 69-48)
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%x ",spi_receive());
    }
    printf("\n\r");

    // Read C_SIZE field (bits 69-48)
    uint32_t cSize = 0;
    cSize |= (spi_receive() & 0x3F) << 16;
    cSize |= spi_receive() << 8;
    cSize |= spi_receive();

    printf("cSize %x\n\r",cSize);

    // Calculate sector count (capacity in sectors)
    uint32_t sectorCount = (cSize + 1) * 1024;

    // Skip CRC bytes
    spi_receive();
    spi_receive();
    
    printf("SectorCount = %d \n\r",sectorCount);

    return sectorCount;
}

void sd_card_init(){
    uint8_t res[20];
    
    SD_DESELECT();
    SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x01;                   //ensure clock is high

    //allow the card to reset etc
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 80; i++) { 
        SD_CARD_BASE_ADDRESS = 0x01;                            //write value
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x00;               //clock low
        SD_CARD_CLOCK_CHIP_SELECT_CONTROL = 0x01;               //clock high        
    }

    SD_SELECT();
    
    SendCMD(CMD0,res,1);

    if (res[0] == 0x01) {
        SendCMD(CMD8,res,5);
        if (res[0] == 0x01) {
            printf(" CMD8 voltage %x\n\r", res[4]);
        }
               
        printf(" Send CMD55 \n\r");
        SendCMD(CMD55,res,1);
        
        if (res[0] == 0x01) {
            SendCMD(ACMD41,res,1);
        } else if (res[0] == 0x05) {
            printf("CMD55 failed, sending CMD1 \n\r");
            SendCMD(CMD1,res,1);
            if (res[0] == 0x01) {
                SendCMD(ACMD41,res,1);
            }
        } else {
            printf("CMD55 FAILED\n\r");
        }
    } else {
        printf("CMD0 FAILED\n\r");
    }

    printf("%d sector count \n\r",get_sector_count());
    
    SD_DESELECT();

    printf(" Initialization complete! \n\r");
}
```

As the init appears to call CMD1 ok and therefore ACMD41, I expect the card to be ready, so why `get_sector_count()` can not return correctly, I'm not sure.

I have also tried reading a block but just get `0x1` and a load of `0xFF`s.

Comment: Here is an working library in C (i tested years ago) maybe this helps you: https://www.dharmanitech.com/2009/01/sd-card-interfacing-with-atmega8-fat32.html

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response.

This looks very helpful.